# Не получается сделать get запрос в react через ajax

Tags: ajax, spring, reactjs, spring-mvc, spring-boot

**Файл index.html , от сюда захожу в компоненту content из index.js:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>React Tutorial</title>
    <!-- Not present in the tutorial. Just for basic styling. -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.3.0/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.3.0/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/marked/0.3.2/marked.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/remarkable@1.7.1/dist/remarkable.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="content"></div>
<script type="text/babel" src="index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Вот файл index.js в котором создана компонента content, здесь идет отправка get запроса по url http://localhost:8182/city/Moscow по которому получаю json и вывожу параметр cod на страницу html:**

```
var CommentBox = React.createClass({
    loadCommentsFromServer: function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.props.url,
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                this.setState({data: data});
            }.bind(this),
            error: function(xhr, status, err) {
                console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
            }.bind(this)
        });
    },
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {data: []};
    },
    componentDidMount: function() {
        this.loadCommentsFromServer();

    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="commentBox">
                <h1>Comments</h1>
                <CommentList data={this.state.data} />

            </div>
        );
    }
});

var CommentList = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var commentNodes = this.props.data.map(function(comment) {
            return (
                <Comment cod={comment.cod} key={comment.id}>
                    {comment.cod}
                </Comment>
            );
        });
        return (
            <div className="commentList">
                {commentNodes}
            </div>
        );
    }
});
var Comment = React.createClass({
    rawMarkup: function() {
        var rawMarkup = marked(this.props.children.toString(), {sanitize: true});
        return { __html: rawMarkup };
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="comment">
                <h2 className="commentCod">
                    {this.props.cod}
                </h2>
                <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.rawMarkup()} />
            </div>
        );
    }
});



ReactDOM.render(
    <CommentBox url="http://localhost:8182/city/Moscow"  />,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

**После отправки get запроса происходит ошибка в браузере. Вот логи браузера с ошибкой:**

```
d2xvc2nqkduarq.cloudfront.net/zr/js/adrns_c.js#HitachiXHTS547550A9E384_J2100050E8Z9HBE8Z9HBX Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
babel.min.js:12 You are using the in-browser Babel transformer. Be sure to precompile your scripts for production - https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/
u @ babel.min.js:12
:8080/favicon.ico Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8182/city/Moscow?_=1505505411770. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.
index.js:14 http://localhost:8182/city/Moscow error
```

[image: проверка get запроса в soapui]

Comment: А где код бэкенда? Он сейчас более актуален для решения вопроса

Comment: запрос бекенда я проверял в soapui , json приходит с содержимым

Comment: прикрепил картинку с проверкой сервера бекенда

Comment: Через SoapUI так же, как и через Postman может работать. Нужен контроллер бэкенда, куда уходит запрос

Comment: backend https://github.com/gibkin/TestWeather тут можно посмотреть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На стороне бэкенда необходимо создать класс:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
    }
}
```

И в вашем контроллере, который принимает запрос, добавьте аннотацию @CrossOrigin:

```
@CrossOrigin 
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class HomeController
```

Comment: а WebConfig добавлять в корень проекта?

Comment: Можно прям рядом с классом Main, можно создать пакет config и запихнуть туда

Comment: а @SptingBootApplication его увидит? это же будет как бин?

Comment: Да, увидит, он помечен аннотацией @Configuration

Comment: Огромное спасибо!!!

Comment: @Санаев успехов!